# Image rendering issue in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing some problems in rendering images on browsers, in my application images are displayed one by on clicking next button in a container.Some times image does not render in the container ,by using firebug i see image source is properly assigned to the img tag but it does not display in the container.I use below mentioned code snippet for assigning image source at run time.

```
imageObject.attr('src',imagePath)
```

In the net tab of firebug i see that for such cases image requested is completed but in the response tab it shows blank but for displayed images it shows the complete image in response.This issue occurs on High resolution images(400 dpi,500 dpi and 600 dpi).Once i close browser and again restart then image gets displayed but after some images issue again persist.I also cleared the cache but the issue still persist.

I am not getting any clue why it happens,please give some suggestions if it a coding mistake or some browser rendering issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from what i understood, i think i have run into the same issue a long time ago. what you need do is fix the width and height attribute for your <img> tag, that way you won't have troubles with lower or higher resolutions images.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion but in our application images size is calculated on run time in jquery to fit to the container, are you saying that initially i should set height and width in HTML then i can change it on run time or some thing else